# php codeigniter - strtotime error

Tags: codeigniter

Getting strtotime error in php-codeigniter and the problem arises only in windows 7 not in windows xp.
**Error : [2048] strtotime() [function.strtotime]:** It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '5.5/no DST' instead

Any help.

Comment: What's funny is that if you google the error message, the only thing you see is a ton of websites suffering from the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini file, put this (or your own timezone):

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

Comment: Yes. I checked it after restarting the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to ignore this error if the time isn't critical. Change error_reporting from E_STRICT to hide the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without overriding php.ini file you can put the following code in your page

`$default_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set($default_timezone);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

UTC stands for universal time zone, or you can set according to the country you want to set.

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) page.